# How do I get a quick launch bar in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

The pin programs to the taskbar is nifty, but I miss my old quicklaunch bar.

How do I get a quick launch bar in Windows 7 like XP had ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Right click on a empty space on the
   taskbar and click on New Tool.
2. In the Folder line, type or copy:
   %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
3. Click on the Select Folder button.
4. You now have a Quick Launch toolbar on the taskbar.
5. To Expand the Quick Launch Toolbar -

   A) Unlock the taskbar.

   B) Left click on the dotted lines and hold, then drag it to the left or right to adjust to unhide all of the icons. Release the left click when done. 
      C) Lock the taskbar.
6. To Remove Quick Launch Toolbar Icon Text or Title -

   A) Unlock the taskbar.

   B) Right click on the Quick Launch toolbar title name, then uncheck the Show Text and Show Title by clicking on them.

   C) Lock the taskbar.
7. To Have Small or Large Icons for Quick Launch Toolbar -

   A) Unlock the taskbar.

   B) Right click on the Quick Launch toolbar title name, then click on View and select to have Large Icons or Small Icons.

   C) Lock the taskbar.
8. To Have Quick Launch Toolbar on Left Side of Taskbar -

   A) Unlock the taskbar.

   B) Left click on the dotted lines of the pinned taskbar programs of the left side and hold, then drag it to the right past the Quick Launch toolbar and release.

   C) The Quick Launch toolbar is now on the left side of the taskbar.

   D) Left click on the dotted lines of these and hold and drag them to make any adjustments to how you want them place on the taskbar.

   9. To get icons stacked in the bar, just click  & drag the top edge of the quick launch bar (when parked at the bottom of the screen). Drag until icons stack in rows of two. If you want to have a three row configuration, drag even more. This is best done when icons are small. A very useful feature as one can add many more icons for launching programs from the quick launch bar. After you are done, drag the dotted line on right of the quick launch bar to left until there is no more gap left and all the icons you want to see are visible. This conserves space on the task bar to show as many open applications comfortably without creating hidden rows.

Comment: You can't use folders as buttons using this approach.
see this answer instead http://superuser.com/questions/23375/windows-7-taskbar-create-popup-menus/341118#341118

Answer (score 12):

Actually by "pinning" your applications to the taskbar you have the same functionality as the 'old quicklaunch bar'. Or am I missing something?

OTOH, by reading [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/19745/how-can-i-pin-a-txt-file-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7), i realise that you have to click 2 times if you've put a shortcut to a document in the taskbar (which isn't the same behaviour as the old style quick launch bar). But that question has [an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/19745/how-can-i-pin-a-txt-file-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/19751#19751) which describes how to enable that again.

Comment: I usually expand the taskbar to 2 rows. pinning apps seems to do layout similar to minimized apps in a left to right order, it looks very very silly with a 2 row taskbar. The icons for the pinned apps are way way too big, theres alot of usseless space around them. So to me this is not the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

You can easily get the Quick Launch bar back with a simple configuration change. I've put together a walk-through guide to doing so.

[Add the Quick Launch Bar to the Taskbar in Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/add-the-quick-launch-bar-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/)

[image]

Comment: This isn't just like the XP taskbar, because the quick launch bar can't be docked outside of the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Right click taskbar > Toolbars > Links

Drag 'n drop shortcuts directly into Links.

Use Links like an old-style quicklaunch with too many icons in it.

Comment: This does not work due to internet explorer security nag bug. Anything in Links falls under aegis of internet explorer security settings, and it will have to be turned off to run normal programs here. Windows nanny state will reset this sometimes, and you have to fight it. Waste of time.

Comment: it never stopped working for me http://superuser.com/questions/23375/windows-7-taskbar-create-popup-menus/341118#341118

Answer (score 1):

a bit OT, but here's a neat trick get a functional recycle bin icon on your taskbar (by way of the quick launch bar):

[image]

1. Right click in some empty space on your taskbar and choose toolbars -> new toolbar from the menu
2. Paste **%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch** into the "folder" box and click select folder.
3. Drag the recycle bin icon from your desktop onto the newly-created toolbar.
4. Position the bin icon so it's first in line.

You're done! All that's left to do is to grab the slider and place the toolbar where you want it, and shut off the title and text labels if you want a seamless look. To do that, right-click the slider and untick show title and show text.

[Source](http://www.techspot.com/guides/196-recycle-bin-on-windows-7-taskbar/)

and credits to Lee M. @ downloadsquad.com for this nice find.

Comment: Super Tip , thanks - that was just implemented, with a slight enhancments. I I created a new folder called: Quick Trash, since Quick Launch has already enough icons. Also remove the recycle bin from the desktop - Desktop settings.

Answer (score 0):

The other methods listed will allow you to put the quick launch bar back on the start menu, but that still isn't the same as XP's in that you can't move it off the taskbar as a floating window or dock it to a side somewhere.  My workaround so far has been to use [ObjectDock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/).