# Can I pin a file to the taskbar in Windows 7? If I can, how?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

For example, I have a password protected .ODT file that I use to manage login information. I would like to pin this file to the taskbar so I can click it to open the file in OpenOffice.org (or whatever my default application for .ODT files happens to be).

This is similar to [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/19745/how-can-i-pin-a-txt-file-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7), but the asker of that question appears to have wanted to pin the file to a jump list for a particular program, or at least that was the answer he accepted. I want to pin the file itself to the taskbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it straight away, since dragging the file to the taskbar results in the associated *program* getting pinned to the taskbar, but the file is pinned to the jumplist.

What you **can** do is, once the program is pinned,right click on it, goto properties and append the file location in the target. Most programs **should** open the file provided as an argument. Have a look at the screenshot to make it more clear:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it doesn't appear that the exact feature I want exists in Windows. This is probably the best I'm going to get for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [Pin Files, Folders, and Favorites to the Taskbar in Windows 7 beta 1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd441705.aspx)

> when you drag a file onto the Taskbar,
>   you are given the option to pin the
>   file to its associated application. So
>   if you drag a Word document onto the
>   Taskbar, you get the option to “Pin to
>   Word”. If the application is already
>   pinned to your Taskbar, the file is
>   pinned to it and will appear in the
>   app’s right-click menu. And no worries
>   if the application isn’t already
>   pinned to the Taskbar, that step is
>   done automatically and the file pinned
>   to the app.

I imagine that for this to work, .ODT must be already registered as handled by the correct word processor.

Comment: ODT is registered, at least on my computer. That's good to note, though.