# How to pin sites to the taskbar in Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, internet-explorer-8

How can I pin any site to IE8 icon in the Windows 7 taskbar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want a button on the taskbar that opens the specific site. 
One way is to create a shortcut to the site on the desktop, then drag it to the taskbar.

Otherwise, you can pin a site to the jump list in IE8. Launch IE8 and rightclick on the taskbar icon. It will pop up a list of recently opened sites. Move your mouse over the one you want, and click the push pin button shown on the right. Then the site will always appear when you rightclick on the taskbar button and you can directly open it. (You'll have to have opened the site previously at least once in IE for this to work).

**Edit**: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/19745/how-can-i-pin-a-txt-file-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7) answer is meant for Notepad and text files, but illustrates the problem correctly. Reassociate the `.url` extension with IE and then it should show up in the jump list.

Comment: Hi, @Rex, I cannot see the jump list. Moreover since I have Chrome already pinned, any attempt to pin a site to taskbar is it pinned to Chrome instead of IE.

Comment: You'll have to make IE your default browser, or reassociate the .url file type (that denotes an internet shortcut) to open with IE instead of chrome. (Control panel -> default programs -> set your default programs, then choose IE from the list and associate it to .url)