# Windows 7 TaskBar Explorer Icon Pins

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

If I want to add a shortcut to any folder on my HD it pins them to the "Pinned" section of the Windows Explorer icon on my Taskbar.  So to get to one of these shortcuts, I have to right click on the icon then click on the specific shortcut.

Is there a way to add icons on the Taskbar for each of these shortcuts?

Comment: You don't HAVE to right click. You can left click and hold while dragging upwards and get the JumpList. It's makes it feel more like a touch screen.

Comment: Just found [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/19726/how-do-i-get-a-quick-launch-bar-in-windows-7), which looks like it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually pin the folder to Windows 7 tasbar (and I don't mean that it appears in the jump list).

[image]

1. First, create a new shortcut (right-click > new > shortcut)
2. in the shortcut, you should be keying in the value like this *%systemdrive%\explorer.exe /E::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}* for a shortcut to "My Computer"
3. Right-click the shortcut, and choose "Pin to Taskbar".

There ya go - cumbersome, but hey it works. For a list of other codes to different system folders (such as "My Documents"), check this [page](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/02/07/command-line-switches-to-display-special-objects-or-folders-when-opening-windows-explorer/) out. If you want to have a shortcut to a normal folder (not any of 7's preset folders), you can just use this shortcut value :

> %systemdrive%\explorer.exe /E "C:\Users\scoopdreams\worlddomination"

That will let me directly access my world domination plans with one-click.

P.S You can also change the icon of the shortcut, and then re-pin to the taskbar with the new icon. Also a tip, you might want to move the shortcut to some out-of-the-way folders, so it doesn't get in the way.

Comment: works perfect, thanx

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this would be to create a folder full of shortcuts to these locations. Then pin the shortcut to the taskbar. Remember to change the shortcut icon before you pin it to the taskbar.

Comment: This still pins it to the "Windows Explorer" icon. And RE: your comment above, that is good to know and better, but not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Well I'm on linux right now. I thought that would work. When I get home I'll try and see if I can find something that will be of more help. Sorry ;-)